# Model Not Loading

Tags: database, model, resources

I created a custom module and I want to use it to save some data in the database. I can retrieve the model class, but when I try to load the content it gives an error.

My config file:

```
        <models>
            <credito>
                <class>Sobreescrita_Credito_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>credito_resource</resourceModel>
            </credito>
            <credito_resource>
                <class>Sobreescrita_Credito_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <solicitacao>
                        <table>solicitacoes</table>
                    </solicitacao>
                </entities>
            </credito_resource>
        </models>
```

My model class:

```
<?php
class Sobreescrita_Credito_Model_Solicitacao extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('credito/solicitacao');
        Mage::log("model");
    }
}
```

My resource class:

```
<?php
class Sobreescrita_Credito_Model_Resource_Solicitacao extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('credito/solicitacao', 'solicitacao_id');
        Mage::log("resource");
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public function solicitarAction(){

        echo get_class(Mage::getModel('credito/solicitacao'));
        $solicitacao = Mage::getModel('credito/solicitacao');
        $solicitacao->load(1);
        var_dump($solicitacao->getData());
    }
```

My table name is 'solicitacoes' and I have a row which id is '1'.

It does not work. However, If I change the last two lines of my controller to that:

```
//$solicitacao->load(1);
var_dump($solicitacao->getData());
```

It does not give the error, but shows an empty array like the following:

```
Sobreescrita_Credito_Model_Solicitacao
C:\wamp64\www\magento\app\code\local\Sobreescrita\Credito\controllers\IndexController.php:24:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did. Everything is fine with the code actually. My problem was that I am using an extension that adds a prefix to all table names and I forgot to add that in my table name when I created it